# How to override Styles.Render or Scripts.Render to serve script resource and style resource from cookieless domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-optimization

After read this [Cookieless domain for bundling and static resources](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/10/aspnet-mvc-4-cookieless-domain-for-bundling-and-static-resources.html), I want to use the bundles to serve scripts and styles from cookieless domain.

How to override the Styles.Render or Scripts.Render  ?

Any suggestion maybe useful, hope your reply!

Comment: after asked the author on twitter [here](https://twitter.com/XqShimron/status/400506623954649088), I got the answer last night. If you are interested the implementation， check [ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework & Cookieless Domain](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2013/11/updated-aspnet-web-optimization-framework-and-cookieless-domain.html)